# Angular Material tabs not showing content

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm trying to create a material tab group like [this one](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview) in the Angular Material component documentation.

The problem I'm encountering is that the content of the tabs isn't loading/showing. I've copied the exact code from the docs, but still no luck.

The code I used:

```
<mat-tab-group>

  <mat-tab label="One">
    <h1>Some tab content</h1>
    <p>...</p>
  </mat-tab>

  <mat-tab label="Two">
    <h1>Some more tab content</h1>
    <p>...</p>
  </mat-tab>

</mat-tab-group>
```

[I've recreated the issue on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qpmqxa)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to import `BrowserAnimationsModule` in your `app.module.ts` file:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

and add it to the imports array:

```
imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ...
```

Also you don't need to import `NoopAnimationPlayer`

See [updated blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nvaxfp?file=main.ts).

Comment: Wow, I've been digging into this problem all day and this answer solved it for me! I didn't see this anywhere in their Tabs documentation. Maybe it's part of the basic setup, I'm not sure. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Great and quick answer.
too bad it's not written in their documentation :(